# Как настроить routes asp.net mvc, чтоб маршрут типа localhost/name не конфликтовал с маршрутом localhost/Home/Index

Tags: asp.net-mvc

В общем есть роутер:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserUrl",
            url: "{url}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "UserURL", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = "Users"}
        );
```

Сам он отрабатывает хорошо, но перестал обрабатывать другие контроллеры. 
localhost/Home/Index и localhost/Home не открывается и подобные адреса.

Подскажите как настроить роутер, чтоб он делал исключения на обработку Home и т.д.

Comment: .Попробуите заменить `name: "UserUrl"` на `name: "Default"` , ведь 
далее идущая строка `defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "UserURL", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`  - это всего лишь путь соединения по умолчанию , метод UserURL в контроллере Users
и попробуйте убрать `constraints: new { controller = "Users"}`, 
и посмотреть что получится .
Все остальные пути у вас должны работать без проблем, 
вот здесь более подробно можно прочитать https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/6.1.php

Comment: если вы хотите при запуске приложения на отладку всегда соединяться с заданным вами маршрутом `controller = "Users", action = "UserURL", id = UrlParameter.Optional`, то это нужно указать в настройках проекта , там есть что то типа `Стартовой страницы `, где  нужно прописать контроллер и метод ...

Comment: Далее у меня так же идет router c name: Default. constraints я изначально делал чтоб данная маршрутизация работала лишь на контроллере Users. Но по каким то не понятным причинам, данное правило маршрутизации так же распространяется на другие контроллеры.